# Creating a "mountable" File System, where to start?

Tags: c++, c, filesystems

A friend and I are thinking about creating a simple file system for learning purposes.  We're going to write it in C/C++, and try to get it to a mountable state from within linux.  We've both been coding or over 16 years (32 combined), so I suppose its just a matter of finding some documentation, and a ton of learning.

My question is, where could I find out more information? (Documentation for creating a file system, requirements of mounting a file system in linux, etc)

Where do we start?

Edit: I should also mention, this would not be a boot-able file system, just a file system used for storage, though I am not too sure if that matters or not.

Comment: Wow, 16 years of experience and still refer to C and C++ as one language, "C/C++".  One would hope for difference with all those years of experience.

Comment: Perhaps for the simple people like yourself, I should have said c OR c++ which is what was infering.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't have much experience with this, but FUSE ("Filesystem in Userspace") seems to be the way to go - see http://fuse.sourceforge.net, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace

Comment: Yes, FUSE is definitely the way to get into this.  Once you understand all the terminology and issues, and you've got a stable and working FUSE implementation, you can then think about moving to an in-kernel implementation.